# How can I redirect url with .htaccess like instagram?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

If the link does not have any value, redirect to index.php.

```
Example;
www.mydomain.com/     --> index.php
```

If the link is www.example.com/post/value, redirect to post.php.

```
Example;
www.mydomain.com/post/cDfS58Q     --> post.php
```

If the link only consists of value, redirect to profile.php.

```
Example;
www.mydomain.com/jhon.34     --> profile.php
```

My test:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9a-zA-Z-_/.]+)$ post.php?$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_/.]+)$ profile.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

but they all go to post.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in a different way ;

htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ post.php?$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?$1 [QSA]
```

index.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {

    //Profile.php will be included here.
    echo "You are in profile now.";

 }else {
    //Homepage.php will be included here.
    echo "You are in profile now.";
 }
?>
```

Url : www.localhost.com/adsasd

Output :  `You are in profile now.`

Url : www.localhost.com/

Output :  `You are in homepage now.`

Answer (score 1):

Set the rewrite rules for each scenario except for the link that does not have any value. The default file that opens when visiting a website is the `index` file so you don't need to explicitly set it.

Go from longest `URI` to smallest because the condition of the smaller `URI` usually satisfies the conditions for the bigger `URI`.

Try somethig like this:

```
# Mod Rewrite setup
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# First enter the one with the longest URI 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?post/([0-9a-zA-Z-_/.]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /post.php?data=%1 [NC,L]

# Then the one with only value
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z-_/.]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?data=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where is the location of your `.htaccess` file? is it in the `public_html` directory of `www.mydomain.com`?

Comment: localhost/www/.htaccess

Comment: RewriteRule ^p/([0-9a-zA-Z-_/.]+)$ post.php?$1 [QSA,L] RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ profile.php?$1 [QSA,L]

This is working but slash forced

Comment: Try again please with the code above. I edited it, it should work. (this is how my server is set up). If it doesn't work what error are you getting `500`, `load timeout`, ...?